# Excel VBA, Speeding up a For loop through a range

Tags: excel, vba, performance, loops

I have a single sheet Excel file that contains 105 columns and 6,000+ (and growing) rows.

Each column represents a resource and each row is a time stamp.

Each cell contains a 1 (resource full) or a 0 (resource empty)

I need to count the number of times a column changes from 1 to 0 or 0 to 1.

I am currently using two loops to allow me to loop through a range by columns.

```
cLAST = Range("XFD2").End(xlToLeft).Column
rLAST = Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Set rng = Range("B5", Cells(rLAST, cLAST))
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
TimerStart = Timer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    For lLoop = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        TimerStart = Timer
        For Each i In rng.Columns(lLoop).Cells
            If Cells(3, i.Column).Value = 0 Then
                GoTo MidLoop
            End If
            If Len(i.Offset(1, 0).Value) > 0 Then
                If i.Value <> i.Offset(1, 0).Value Then
                    i.Value = "Pass"
                End If
            End If
MidLoop:
            If i.Row Mod 1000 = 0 Then
                Debug.Print i.Row, rLAST, i.Column, cLAST
            End If
    Next i
    TimerStop = Timer
    Debug.Print TimerStop - TimerStart
Next lLoop
objXL.Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
objXL.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

The loop for each column is taking about 60 seconds or about an hour and 45 minutes for the entire process.

Any ideas on speeding this up would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Kevin

Comment: Read all the data into a `Variant` array and loop the array.

Comment: Cell-by-cell access in Excel is super-slow compared to reading a range into an array and looping over the array.

Comment: Can you explain the role of the value in Row 3 of each column?

Comment: Your posted (too slow?) code doesn't match your description of what you want to do?  Is the counting of value changes on top of this existing code?  What should be done with the counts?

Comment: Mr. Williams,  Row 3 contains the sum of the column.  If the column is 0 it skips that loop. 
 The code marks each 1 to 0 or 0 to 1 change as "Pass", a CountIf formula counts the number "Pass".  I am going to try passing the range to an array and looping through the array.

Comment: OK then my posted code should work as-is

Answer (score 0):

This is based on your posted code (but ignoring checking the Row 3 value for each column as I'm not too clear on what that's intended to do):

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim lastCol As Long, lastRow As Long, numRows As Long, nxt
    Dim ws As Worksheet, data, colNum As Long, rowNum As Long
    Dim t, Rng As Range

    t = Timer
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'or whatever
    lastCol = ws.Cells(2, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = ws.Range("B5", ws.Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
    numRows = Rng.Rows.Count
    
    data = Rng.Value 'read the whole range
    
    For colNum = 1 To Rng.Columns.Count
        For rowNum = 1 To numRows - 1
            nxt = data(rowNum + 1, colNum)
            If Len(nxt) > 0 Then
                If nxt <> data(rowNum, colNum) Then
                    data(rowNum, colNum) = "Pass"
                End If
            End If
        Next rowNum
    Next colNum
    
    Rng.Value = data 'return the data
    
    Debug.Print "Done in " & (Timer - t) & " secs"
    
End Sub
```

This processed a range of approx 6k rows x 100 columns in about a second.

Comment: This should be quick! Looping thru an array is very fast.